# Detecting and Removing GPS coordinates of "0.0000, 0.00000"(non fixed) data using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spyder

I am doing a vehicle monitoring process with raw data files. 
As of now, some cleaning up was done before the issue surface. As I have inconsistent data, It causes some problem to me. Data includes "Model(v,w,x,y and z), Timestamp, Latitude, Longitude and Mode(0,2,4,8)".

The objective of this process is to calculate distance and duration with cleaning of data

I have successfully done calculating of duration using the timestamp with respect to both Model and Mode. I have also successfully done calculating the distance between rows using coordinates and haversine formula. HERE COMES THE PROBLEM:

So I can only successfully calculate the distance among rows if both Lat & Long is present and in the right format (e.g. 1.035436, 103.234623). Data received can be of empty field which causes an error. This error was solved by identifying the empty field and removing the line (As without lat long, the data is useless)

```
 mydataset = mydataset[mydataset['Mode'].notnull()]     #for removing empty mode
 mydataset = mydataset[mydataset['Latitude'].notnull()]       #for removing empty latitude
```

But there are lat long received as 0.00000000,0.00000000 and i would like to remove rows with lat long in this numbers. Some methods has been tried but it doesnt work. I've tried identifying the 0 and remove it using:

```
mydataset = mydataset[(mydataset[['Latitude','Longitude']] != 0).all(axis=1)]
```

and

```
mydataset = mydataset[(mydataset.Latitude != 0).any()]
```

Due to confidential data and code, I cannot provide much but would like to know why the above 2 method do not work and if possible, can anyone advice me on how to tackle with such problem?

Thank you! Much appreciate and Thank you for your time!

Some fake data are as shown below:

```
,Model,Timestamp,Longitude,Latitude,Mode
0,x,1970-01-19 01:29:17.058,103.235623,1.045436,0
1,x,1970-01-19 01:29:22.058,0.00000000,0.00000000,0  #Would like to remove this row
2,x,1970-01-19 01:29:27.058,103.234813,1.038436,2
3,x,1970-01-19 01:29:32.058,103.235623,1.039436,2
4,x,1970-01-19 01:29:38.058,103.234123,1.036436,0
5,x,1970-01-19 01:29:38.058,,,0 #removed via the code above
```

Comment: You may not be able to provide the exact data you are using, but can you provide some fake data in the same format showing the issue you are having?

Comment: @asongtoruin Hi, updated. Sorry for any inconvenience caused

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if i understood correctly, do you need something like this ?

Sample df

```
Lat,Long
55.6,22.06
0.00000000,0.00000000
56.056,22.10

df1 = df[df[['Lat','Long']] != 0].dropna(how='any').reset_index(drop= True)
print(df1)
      Lat   Long
0  55.600  22.06
1  56.056  22.10
```

Comment: Hello, Yes you understood correctly but the code proposed by you could not solve my problem as I have a calculation of distance using "  distdura['dist'] = np.concatenate(distdura.groupby(["Model"]).apply(lambda x: haversine(x['Latitude'],x['Longitude'],
             x['Latitude'].shift(),x['Longitude'].shift())).values)" for my distance calculation, it actually caused an error "ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate"

Comment: @ThanksForHelping you need to calculate distance between two different consecutive coordinates ?